# Completely Scalable Website similar to SVGs and PowerPoints

Tags: javascript, html, css, aspect-ratio

Good morning/evening, hope you're having a great day. I had a problem I've been postponing for the last couple of months.

**Short Question:** Is there a way I can make my website scale, everything in it scale, from text to images, to tables,... when the window size is changed?

**Long Question:** I've been working on a program that is similar to PowerPoint, I have been giving a lot of webinars/events in my local area and PowerPoint isn't that good for programmers, or if you want to use it for teaching, there is a lot of repetitive things I can automate with programming. Now I have one problem, I just can't figure out what can I do to make a presentation scalable just like how PowerPoint is doing so, I had an idea and that was just to create each slide as an SVG image, or at least use an SVG tag but with the ForeignObject tag and just stick my HTML code in it, but that is ugly coding and will lead to some trouble. On the other hand, if I ditch SVGs and use something like media queries for adjusting the font size, it wont work, since the font will not scale nicely and some text may go to the next line and you know what I mean.

Is there anything I can do about this? I know that this question is too lengthy and I'm sorry. I can code in HTML, CSS, JavaScript and (soon React) if that helps.

Comment: I believe you have already looked into defining the sizes of your elements in `vh` and `vw`. And by the way, it seems like an interesting project :)

Comment: Using `vh` and `vw` will not be so accurate, when resizing the page some text may hop onto the next line

Comment: Have a look at this example "Proportional scaling of everything"  https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/#proportional-scaling-of-everything